# no such file or directory mkdir

Tags: directory

```
# sudo mkdir /hadoop-data/hadoopmaster/hdfs/namenode

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/hadoop-data/hadoopmaster/hdfs/namenode’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 9):

One of the following directories does not exist:

```
/hadoop-data/hadoopmaster/hdfs/
/hadoop-data/hadoopmaster/
/hadoop-data/
```

To ensure that all of the required directories are created, add the `-p` option, to make `p`arent directories as needed:

```
sudo mkdir -p /hadoop-data/hadoopmaster/hdfs/namenode
```

Comment: So what I have to type?

Comment: Use `sudo mkdir -p /hadoop-data/hadoopmaster/hdfs/namenode` (note the `-p`) to create the missing parent directories, too.

Comment: Ok.................................